# Uniform convergence - fancy way of saying sequence of functions is Cauchy?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Is uniform convergence a fancy way of saying a sequence of functions is Cauchy?

It seems a sequence of functions $\{f_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is uniformly convergent if  $n>m>N$, $\|f_n-f_m\|\lt \epsilon$

---

Are they equivalent?

Does uniform convergence of a sequence of functions $\implies$ sequence of functions is Cauchy

What about the converse?

Comment: uniform convergence is equivalent to convergence in $||\cdot||_{\infty}$ norm

Comment: A sequence is "Cauchy" is defined more generally in a metric space.  So when you study that setting, you will see that "a sequence of functions is Cauchy" can have many meanings: one for each metric for functions.

Comment: As user160738 said, uniform convergence is really just convergence in your function space when you give it the $L^{\infty}$ norm.  I think the point is that while looking at pointwise convergence is sometimes useful, it unfortunately doesn't correspond to convergence in a normed function space.

Comment: Any convergent sequence (of points or functions, and for any choice of metric) is automatically Cauchy, however the reverse, that any Cauchy sequence converges, is only true if your space is complete.